# Spring Batch job parameters limited to 250 chars?

Tags: java, oracle, spring, spring-batch

I'm setting up a Spring Batch Job with [ItemReader/ItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html) to export datasets from an Oracle DB to CSV/Excel/PDF. For the reader part I'm using the [JdbcCursorItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html).

By default it is necessary to pass the SQL statement to the reader to extract the datasets - this is my reader configuration:

```
<bean id="readErgebnis" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="#{jobParameters['stmt']}" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="myFancyRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

So I added the SQL statement to the JobParametersBuilder...

```
JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder(); 
builder.addString("stmt", sql);
```

That should be fine. However executing the job fails with an `SQLException`.

Now I know that Spring Batch is logging everything to it's logging tables, and there is the problem - the parameter string (containing the SQL) is limited to 250 characters. See the definition of the BATCH_JOB_PARAMS table:

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_PARAMS  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ,
    TYPE_CD VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL ,
    KEY_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL , 
    STRING_VAL VARCHAR2(250), 
    DATE_VAL TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ,
    LONG_VAL NUMBER(19,0) ,
    DOUBLE_VAL NUMBER ,
    constraint JOB_INST_PARAMS_FK foreign key (JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
);
```

Spring Batch stores every job parameter in a new row, therefore the SQL statement goes into the STRING_VAL column which is limited to 250 characters. I checked the DDLs for the other database systems (MySQL and DB2), it seems to be limited to 250 characters everywhere. I changed that column to `CLOB` now, works fine and my job runs.

My question: I can hardly believe that it is intended to store job parameters limited to  250 characters via batch jobs. So is there a better implementation for my scenario or is it intended to change the default values for the parameter columns in the BATCH_JOB_PARAMS table?

Comment: no, you should never modify the metadata schema.  See my response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DO not pass the SQL as a parameter of the job.  Instead create a Class extending the JdbcCursorItemReader that implements the InitializingBean.

```
package xxx.readers;

public class MyReader  extends  JdbcCursorItemReader<AnObjet> implements InitializingBean{


@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // set the SQL

    String SELECT_PAYMENT = "SELECT * from table"
    super.setSql(SELECT_PAYMENT);

    }
}
```

This way your sql will be set when your beans are initialized at start up by the spring context.

if you need to add a where clause, use PreparedStatementSetter and add it to the config.

```
    <bean id="myReader" class="xxx.readers.MyReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="aDataSource" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="aMapper" />     
    <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="yourPreparedStatementSetter" />
</bean>
```

A preparedStatementSetter example :

```
package fcdq.iemt.batch.concilliation.utils;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.SQLException;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;



 @Component("aPrStatSetter")
 public class RunNoSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter {


public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ps.setString(1, "hello");
    ps.setString(2, "Hola");
    ps.setTimestamp(3, aTimestamp);
}
 }
```

The preparedStatementSetter will be called at run time to replace the ? in your where clause.

hope it help.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However it is more like a workaround since I would like to log the executed SQL statement - and that information is lost now. Of course it would be possible to log the statement in a different (custom) log table. Would you recommend that or is there another way? Are there any more reasons not to pass the SQL as parameter besides the logging problem?

Comment: I would log the SQL with log4j in files or another database.  The metadata of srping is used to control and know the state of the job.  For example, if you only pass the SQL in the job parameter, you will find that your job can only be run once... since spring batch does not let you run 2 job with the same parameters value.  Thats how he knows if a job did run or not.  your SQL is more a step parameter then a job.  In the end, i would say that by design it is wrong to pass SQL as job parameter.  Imagine if your job would have 10 steps...you would have to pass 10 SQL!!

Comment: Good point. My job is a single-step one but of course that can change anytime.